# Error método editar en java ee (JSP)

Tags: java, formularios, jsp

estoy teniendo un error que desconozco, ya que no me muestra realmente ningún error en el código. El error que me da es el siguiente:

[image: El error está en la linea 17.]

El código al que hace relación es el siguiente:

**editar.jsp**

```
    <%@page import="modeloDAO.ProductoDAO"%>
    <%@page import="models.Producto"%>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">     
    <title>Modificar producto</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div>
            <%
            
                ProductoDAO dao = new ProductoDAO();
                int id = Integer.parseInt((String)request.getAttribute("idpro"));
                Producto p = (Producto)dao.list(id);
            %>
        
        
            <h1>Modificar producto</h1>
            
            <a href="Controlador?accion=listar">Volver atrás</a>
            
            <form action="Controlador">
                Nombre: <br>
                <input type="text" name="nombreForm" value="<%= p.getNombre() %>"><br>
                Descripcion: <br>
                <input type="text" name="descripcionForm" value="<%= p.getDescripcion() %>"><br>
                Precio: <br>
                <input type="text" name="precioForm" value="<%= p.getPrecio() %>"><br>
                <input type="hidden" name="txtid" value="<%= p.getId() %>">
                <input type="submit" name="accion" value="actualizar">
                
            </form>
        </div>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

El controlador al que llamo desde esta vista con el codigo de editar es el siguiente:

**Controlador.jsp**

```
else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("editar")) {
        request.setAttribute("idpro", request.getParameter("id "));
        
        acceso = edit;
    }
    
    else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("actualizar")) {
        id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtid"));
        String nombre = request.getParameter("nombreForm");
        String descripcion = request.getParameter("descripcionForm");
        String precio = request.getParameter("precioForm");
        p.setId(id);
        p.setNombre(nombre);
        p.setDescripcion(descripcion);
        p.setPrecio(precio);
        dao.edit(p);
        
        acceso = edit;
        
    }
```

En el código aclaro que no me salta ningún error. Compila todo bien, pero en el momento de listar todo y entrar a editar una entrada en concreto, es cuando me salta el error de la imagen. Espero sus respuestas y muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: el request no trae ese atributo y el parseint trabaja sobre un valor nulo

Comment: Me podrías ser tan amable de explicarme el porqué? No entiendo porque no lo trae. Gracias por adelantado.